# Contourplot gives inaccurate ellipses

Tags: plotting, graphics, geometry

I'm trying to draw a family of ellipses with pre-defined foci as follows:

```
    foci = {{-3, 25}, {2, 20}};
    ContourPlot[Tr[EuclideanDistance[#, {x, y}] & /@ foci], {x, -5, 5}, {y, 10, 30},
      Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[Large], Point@foci}]
```

which produces the following output:

[image: ellipses seem skew]

The contours do seem to be ellipses, but not ones with the specified foci, and they also look like their axes are rotated at varying angles. How can I get ellipses with the correct foci?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks fine to me, once you get your aspect ratio proper.

```
foci = {{-3, 25}, {2, 20}};
ContourPlot[
 Total[EuclideanDistance[#, {x, y}] & /@ foci],
 {x, -5, 5}, {y, 10, 30},
 AspectRatio -> 2,
 Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[Large], Point@foci}]
```

[image]

or your horizontal and vertical ranges equal:

```
foci = {{-3, 25}, {2, 20}};
mycontplot = ContourPlot[
  Total[EuclideanDistance[#, {x, y}] & /@ foci],
  {x, -10, 10}, {y, 10, 30},
  Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[Large], Point@foci}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1, `AspectRatio->Automatic` will work in general.